# Wordpress main category name returns 404

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I need to setup category structure like this:

Blog
 - child category
 - child category 2

etc, but when I try to access archive page for Blog category I get a 404 error.

My permalink structure is: %domain%/%category%/%postname%/

Comment: you didn't give enough informations to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

The steps you need to follow to make a category as a child category of another category are:

1.Ensure both the categories exists,assuming categories are named cat1(parent) and cat2(child)
[image]

2.Ensure the parent of the child category is set to parent category(cat1 here)
[image]

3.while adding the post just ensure that the category is appropriately set

[image]

4.Permalink structure should be correct ,such as /%category%/%postname%/

If you just follow the points 1 to 4 your solution would work.